# Django 3.1.7 query parameter separators

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, query-string

With the change in Django 3.1.7 to not allow using `;` as a default query parameter separator, what is the suggestion moving forward? Is there something else that should be used instead?

Where does one specify which query param separators are permitted?

There are the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1.7/) for this version.

Comment: did you tried ampersand (`&`)?

Comment: Yes that's it thanks.